# Windows phone 7 how to add countries to published app

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I´ve published an app to marketplace, but forgot to choose all countries.

Now my app is only availible in USA and Canada. Is there a way to add more countries
to an app after it has been published? Do i have to submit an update?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense posting this in the app-hub forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the apphub dashboard, click on your application, select the last version in the "binary name" dropdown list, then click on "Edit pricing". There you can add the countries you want, and submit the update. As you didn't modify the binary, it should be published faster than a 'traditional' update (about 2-3 days usually).